# How can I load the right hand pane of vim with a new file in linux?

Tags: vim, diff

I want to compare two files(say `A` and `B`) side by side(vertically) in in Vim. I open one of those two files(say A) and as per [this answer in this site](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/1387/28032) issue a <kbd>Ctrl+w v</kbd> . Now both the panels are showing contents of file `A`. How can I see the contents of A in the left had side and B in the right hand side ? I am using Red Hat Linux if that matters .

Comment: `:e <filename>`

Comment: From the command line, i.e. if you don't have a `vim` open already: `vimdiff file1 file2`.  If you don't actually need `vimdiff`, then `vim -O file1 file2`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can skip `Ctrl+w v` and just do:

```
:vert diffsplit <other_filename>
```

Answer (score 1):

You must switch panes in `vim` and then open a new file.

Switch panes with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>.

Once the cursor is in the new pane, open a new file by entering the `vim` command line and using the open file command.

```
:e /some/file/name
```